# How to hide a value in a compiled binary

Tags: go

I want to hide a string constant present in the code. For example, in the following code - the variable `a`'s value can be a secret:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  a := "someStringXYZ"
  fmt.Println(a)
}
```

This is how compiled this go file:

```sh
$ go build -ldflags='-extldflags=-static' abc.go
```

Works fine as well:

```sh
$ ./abc 
someStringXYZ
```

If I use the `strings` command on this binary then I can get the value of the variable `a`.

```sh
$ strings abc | grep XYZ
eq=runtime: val=someStringXYZsrmount errortimer expiredtraceStackTabtriggerRatio=value method xadd64 failedxchg64 failed}
```

Is there a way I can keep this value hidden?

I'm not looking for a solution in which the app will use the AppTokens to get the value from secret storage because then the AppTokens becomes visible.

Comment: "Is there a way I can keep this value hidden?" In a word: no.

There are ways to obfuscate things in compiled code. None are fool-proof, and are thus generally considered not worth the effort. Of course that depends on your reason. If you have truly secret information (like passwords), it's best to find another way to share those.

Comment: If a secret is not required to reconstruct the value, you can only make it harder to obtain, but not impossible

Answer (score 4):

As the comments noted, you can't really make it fully hidden. What you can do, in order to at least hide it from `strings` (if that's all you want), is save it as a `[]byte`, not a `string`, like so:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []byte("someStringXYZ")
    fmt.Println(string(a))
}
```

Now, when I compile and run `strings` on it, it doesn't find "someStringXYZ" anymore. You can still obviously extract it easily, if you tried, and it will obviously show up in memory at some point when it runs, but that might not be your immediate concern (I'm not sure what your application is).

Note that this only works if the literal only appears there in the cast, not anywhere else.

Either way - if you have a token hardcoded, and you need to hide it, you're probably doing something wrong at the design-stage. You should reconsider that design.

Edit: To explain why this method works; I'm not sure, but I think it's because []byte are not stored with a terminating null-byte, or something along those lines. `strings` only finds printable characters of length 4 or longer that end with some unprintable character - so really, we might just be getting lucky. As I said before, but to phrase it differently; Obfuscation is not security. This isn't safe if someStringXYZ is important.